# Gigabyte Z170X Firmware Update without Windows

Tags: motherboard, updates, firmware

I have a Gigabyte Z170X Ultra Gaming motherboard, and I want to

1. Check if there is a firmware update available (I have version F22)
2. Install the firmware update if available

But I'm running Linux, and can't / don't want to use the Windows tools provided by Gigabyte. My motherboad has that "QFlash"-menu which seems to be able to install firmware updates from a FAT32-formatted drive. But I don't know where to get the firmware update files neccessary for this step. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you Google "Gigabyte Z170X Ultra Gaming firmware"?  In three clicks I founds this page : https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-Ultra-Gaming-rev-10#support-dl .  Look in the BIOS section for F23d and download the ZIP.  You can probably use the file inside with that QFlash function.

Comment: Usually the manufacturer would hold the relevant files and usually they are in a self extracting executable. Many archivers can still extract the files from these archives. What have you tried?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is legitimate to miss something on the net even after doing proper research. I don't like this community being so disapproving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firmware (“BIOS”) updates are available *only* from the manufacturer. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gigabyte+Z170X+Ultra+Gaming) will take you [there](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-Ultra-Gaming-rev-10#support-dl).

Download the latest BIOS update, unpack it to some location the Q-Flash utility can access. Use Q-Flash to perform the update. Just follow the on-screen instructions.

Some update tools can also access the Internet without an operating system, and download the update by themselves.